# Zero offered bounties for 50 reputation

Tags: bug, profile-page, bounties

I found a user (currently suspended) that has “[0 offered bounties for 50 reputation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/12123/vadizar?tab=bounties&sort=offered)” (The original text is in Russian due to localisation):

> [image: zero bounties]

I’m not sure, but probably the voting violations (the reason of suspension) have caused this.

In any case the text “for 50 reputation” should not be there.

Comment: Probably caching due to a bounty that was cleared by a moderator.

Comment: @Sonic might as well be "permanent" cache that is synchronized only on demand, e.g. when a new bounty will be offered.

Comment: @nicael we miss you, stop hiding! ;)